# Input year week then output total users per day

Tags: mysql

I have a `users` table

```
id  |  username  |  password  |  created_at
---------------------------------------------------
1   |  foo       |  p4ssw0rd  |  2016-01-01 12:00:00
2   |  bar       |  123456    |  2016-01-02 12:00:00
....
```

How do I achieve this result, having just an input of a **year week** 
(example: `'201605'`, 5th week of 2016)

```
total_users  |  date
------------------------
4            |  2016-01-04
6            |  2016-01-05
7            |  2016-01-06
10           |  2016-01-07
12           |  2016-01-08
12           |  2016-01-09
15           |  2016-01-10
```

As you can see, it's showing the `total_users` per week, a row per day.

I know this is too much to ask and I thank you in advance if you'll try to help me.

Comment: What code have you used to achieve it? Show us. even though it isn't correct.

Comment: Actually, I used many queries trying to achieve this, but the real table structure is a lot more complex than the example I gave above.

Comment: There's no way that that's the 5th week

Comment: @Strawberry Yep it's not. Just a sample input data, not related to the results next to it.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm just saying that the format of the input I want is something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MySQL` WEEK function . MySQL `WEEK()` returns the week number for a given date

```
SELECT count(*) total_users,date(created_at) date
FROM `table` 
where concat(YEAR(created_at),WEEK(created_at))='201605'
group by date(created_at)
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. The rows are displaying the users created on that day, not the `total_users` on that day.

Comment: Okay, in my view, I have <input type="week"> which returns a yearweek. (Example: '201502', which means 2nd week of year 2015). Then I use that yearweek to query against the table to display how much the users have grown each day.

Comment: SELECT count(*) total_users,date(created_at) date
FROM `table` 
where concat(YEAR(created_at),WEEK(created_at))='20165'
group by date(created_at)
order by total_users desc

Comment: @KenthJohnIsrael try this query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(user) as Total_users,
date(created_at) as Date
FROM Users
GROUP BY date(created_at);
```

Regards

Comment: @Rahautos. I did not catch the WHERE requirements. Well done!